# git log --follow filename does not show commit changed that file

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge, git-log

Here what have I done:

- Created development branch from master;
- Modified several files and committed them;
- Merged development branch to master with `--no-commit` parameter;
- Run `git reset --hard` on several files modified in the development branch. As the result master branch contains only several objects from development branch — i.e. I've merge development changes partially;
- I've committed changes in master;
- After some time, master branch was updated by other developers and to update my development branch I merged master branch into it.

I was ready to fact, that my development objects I've not committed to master on my previous merge will be overwritten by files from master. But in the output of the `git log --follow dev-modified-file.txt` I cannot see the commit who overwrote my development changes.

Running  `git log --follow dev-modified-file.txt` on my development branch I can see needed commits with development modifications. But cannot see commits reverting that changes back (actually there is no such commit anyway) but my working tree contains master version of the `dev-modified-file.txt` file, despite there are commits adding development code, but there are no commits deleting that code.

Why?

And how did code from master branch sneak to the my development branch leaving no traces behind?

P.S. If my description is unclear, please ask questions in comments I will be glad to explain and correct this post accordingly.

**EDIT:** After merging my master into development I don't see difference between master and development branch (my omitted changes are gone!) and I don't see commit responsible for that in development branch!

I believe it might be related to merging strategies... But how? You see, how my log in development branch look like:

- I've added changes to file — file in working folder contain that changes.
- I've merged master branch into development — lots of commits came to development branch and my edited file become equal one in the master branch, despite there is no commit responsible for that!

---

I have added changes to the file after merge that changes disappear with no traces left!

Comment: You're on `master` right now when you see no "no commits deleting that code", or on the development branch? I.e. is it that on `master` you don't see the development branch's merged changes, or on the development branch you see `master`'s version unexpectedly?

Comment: On development branch. The development branch is the place where all changes were introduces. During merge to master I applied these changes only partially. And that omitted changes are in development branch only. It's OK that I don't see them on master — I haven't committed them in purpose. But after merging my master into development I don't see difference between master and development branch (my omitted changes are gone!) and I don't see commit responsible for that!

Comment: I would bet the 'merging my master into development' commit. Try `git diff <merge_commit>~1 <merge_commit>` and see what changes it made.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good chance you're not seeing the changes you're looking for because of the history simplification performed by `git log <filename>` in its default mode.  This simplification makes `git log <filename>` not very useful for finding commits that *remove* content.

Try using `git log --follow --simplify-merges dev-modified-file.txt` instead; this changes the history simplification algorithm to make it less aggressive in simplifying away changes that you might care about.  If the history is short enough, and you have gitk installed, you might be able to just browse the history to find what you're looking for: `gitk --simplify-merges dev-modified-file.txt`